# Why Symfony requires doctrine/orm

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Why Symfony requires `doctrine/orm` and `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` at same time?

Shouldn't `doctrine/orm` be a dependency of `doctrine/doctrine-bundle`?

Wouldn't this format allow me to make an invalid combination of doctrine/orm with other doctrine libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` has `doctrine/orm` as an **optional dependency** (`suggests` section of `composer.json`). Here's this bundle's [composer.json](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/composer.json). That means that is it possible to use this bundle without ORM.

Since ORM is optional for doctrine-bundle, Symfony's `composer.json` specifies ORM as dependency to make it required.

Comment: The orm is required for development.  The real question would be why it is optional in production?  Struggling to think of a use case where you would need the bundle in development but not in production.

Comment: @Cerad I guess because it's needed for tests.